# apoc returned path morph into grouped data

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

this is a screenshot of a sample graph:

[image: sample graph]

sample graph data generation:

```
CREATE (r:Red {key:'someid'})
CREATE (t1:Teal)
CREATE (t2:Teal)
CREATE (t3:Teal)
CREATE (t4:Teal)
CREATE (t5:Teal)
CREATE (t6:Teal)
CREATE (r2:Red)
CREATE (b1:Blue)
CREATE (b2:Blue)
CREATE (b3:Blue)
CREATE (b4:Blue)
CREATE (f:FINAL_NODE)
CREATE (r)<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT]-(t1)
CREATE (r)<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT]-(t2)
CREATE (r)<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT]-(t3)
CREATE (r)<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT]-(t4)
CREATE (r)<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT]-(t5)
CREATE (r)<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT]-(t6)
CREATE (t1)<-[:TO_ATL]-(r2)
CREATE (t2)<-[:TO_ATL]-(r2)
CREATE (t3)<-[:TO_ATL]-(r2)
CREATE (t4)<-[:TO_ATL]-(r2)
CREATE (t5)<-[:TO_ATL]-(r2)
CREATE (t6)<-[:TO_ATL]-(r2)
CREATE (r2)<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT]-(b1)
CREATE (r2)<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT]-(b2)
CREATE (r2)<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT]-(b3)
CREATE (r2)<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT]-(b4)
CREATE (b1)-[:TO_FINAL]->(f)
CREATE (b2)-[:TO_FINAL]->(f)
CREATE (b3)-[:TO_FINAL]->(f)
CREATE (b4)-[:TO_FINAL]->(f)
```

if my query looks like this:

```
MATCH (f:Red {key:'someid'}) 
CALL apoc.path.expand(f, '<TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT|<TO_ATL|TO_FINAL>', '>FINAL_NODE',-1,-1) yield path as p

RETURN p
```

when using the browser and looking at the table view, it looks like the data gets returned as singular paths in an array.  So an array within an array.

```
[
  [
     {red},
     {relationship},
     {teal},
     {relationship},
     {red},
     {relationship},
     {blue},
     {relationship},
     {green}
  ],
  [
     {red},
     {relationship},
     {teal},
     {relationship},
     {red},
     {relationship},
     {blue},
     {relationship},
     {green}
  ],
  etc
]
```

the {} being the properties of each node and relationship.

If I use

RETURN Nodes(p)

it just gives me a list of all items without the depth and if I try and use size or length with path, they all are 5 in this instance and doesn't give me the individual nodes.

What I really would like is to be able to recreate the levels of the graph so ideally the data would be returned like this:

```
[
  [
    {red}
  ],[
    {teal},
    {teal},
    {teal},
    {teal},
    {teal},
    {teal}
  ],[
    {red}
  ],[
    {blue},
    {blue},
    {blue},
    {blue},
    {blue},
    {blue},
    {blue}
  ],[
    {green}
  ]
]
```

Is this possible using the expand function or do I need to figure out how to do the same thing with a standard pattern through cypher - i.e. MATCH (r)-[:*]-(final)?

//couple of clarifications:
There could be an arbitrary number of routes and nodes.  So in this example its red, teal, red, blue, green.  It could be red, teal, red, teal, red, blue, green.  Could just be red, blue, green.

I am using C# and the neo4j driver if that makes a difference for what data I can get returned  example of the response I get back from just returning path in C#

```
[{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":20,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":25,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":5,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":20,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":11,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":20,"Properties":{}},{"Id":15,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":25,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":19,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":25,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":20,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":24,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":5,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":20,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":11,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":20,"Properties":{}},{"Id":14,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":24,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":18,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":24,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":20,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":23,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":5,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":20,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":11,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":20,"Properties":{}},{"Id":13,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":23,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":17,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":23,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":20,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":22,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":5,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":20,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":11,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":20,"Properties":{}},{"Id":12,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":22,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":16,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":22,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":5,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":25,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":4,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":5,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":10,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":5,"Properties":{}},{"Id":15,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":25,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":19,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":25,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":5,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":24,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":4,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":5,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":10,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":5,"Properties":{}},{"Id":14,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":24,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":18,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":24,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":5,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":23,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":4,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":5,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":10,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":5,"Properties":{}},{"Id":13,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":23,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":17,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":23,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":5,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":22,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":4,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":5,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":10,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":5,"Properties":{}},{"Id":12,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":22,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":16,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":22,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":4,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":25,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":3,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":4,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":9,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":4,"Properties":{}},{"Id":15,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":25,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":19,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":25,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":4,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":24,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":3,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":4,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":9,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":4,"Properties":{}},{"Id":14,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":24,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":18,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":24,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":4,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":23,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":3,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":4,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":9,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":4,"Properties":{}},{"Id":13,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":23,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":17,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":23,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":4,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":22,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":3,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":4,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":9,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":4,"Properties":{}},{"Id":12,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":22,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":16,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":22,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":3,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":25,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":2,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":3,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":8,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":3,"Properties":{}},{"Id":15,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":25,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":19,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":25,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":3,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":24,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":2,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":3,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":8,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":3,"Properties":{}},{"Id":14,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":24,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":18,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":24,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":3,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":23,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":2,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":3,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":8,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":3,"Properties":{}},{"Id":13,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":23,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":17,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":23,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":3,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":22,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":2,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":3,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":8,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":3,"Properties":{}},{"Id":12,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":22,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":16,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":22,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":2,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":25,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":1,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":2,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":7,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":2,"Properties":{}},{"Id":15,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":25,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":19,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":25,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":2,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":24,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":1,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":2,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":7,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":2,"Properties":{}},{"Id":14,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":24,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":18,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":24,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":2,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":23,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":1,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":2,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":7,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":2,"Properties":{}},{"Id":13,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":23,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":17,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":23,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":2,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":22,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":1,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":2,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":7,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":2,"Properties":{}},{"Id":12,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":22,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":16,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":22,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":1,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":25,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":0,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":1,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":6,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":1,"Properties":{}},{"Id":15,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":25,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":19,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":25,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":1,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":24,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":0,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":1,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":6,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":1,"Properties":{}},{"Id":14,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":24,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":18,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":24,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":1,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":23,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":0,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":1,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":6,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":1,"Properties":{}},{"Id":13,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":23,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":17,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":23,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}},{"p":{"Start":{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},"End":{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}},"Nodes":[{"Id":0,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{"key":"someid"}},{"Id":1,"Labels":["Teal"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":21,"Labels":["Red"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":22,"Labels":["Blue"],"Properties":{}},{"Id":26,"Labels":["FINAL_NODE"],"Properties":{}}],"Relationships":[{"Id":0,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":1,"EndNodeId":0,"Properties":{}},{"Id":6,"Type":"TO_ATL","StartNodeId":21,"EndNodeId":1,"Properties":{}},{"Id":12,"Type":"TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT","StartNodeId":22,"EndNodeId":21,"Properties":{}},{"Id":16,"Type":"TO_FINAL","StartNodeId":22,"EndNodeId":26,"Properties":{}}]}}]
```

[Additional Clarification]

A more specific example is if you are moving animals, you have a source of birth and then you have several movements until you get to market.  so the graph looks looks like the initial screenshot where the red nodes are a certain location that the animal has been moved to and the teal and blue are different types of schedules.  However, the only information I know for sure is what location it is currently at (so what red node) and I want to get to the source of birth (the green node).  The number of movements and locations it has been at are variable.  It may have been moved once or it could have been moved x number of times.  I do tend to know that the paths are limited to 3 labeled relationships.  So while I like the syntax a lot of the apoc procedure, if I can't manipulate that path after getting it, then perhaps I just need to do something like

```
MATCH (f:Red {key:'someid'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (f)<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT|TO_ATL*]-()-[:SOURCE_FOR_INC]->(g:Green)
RETURN g
```

but to me the above will only return f or g and not the path so it would have to be something like this:

```
MATCH (f:Red {key:'someid'})
p = OPTIONAL MATCH (f)<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT|TO_ATL*]-()-[:SOURCE_FOR_INC]->(g:Green)
RETURN p
```

which I believe would give me the path, but be the same scenario as the apoc where I can't morph the data into groups...

Comment: I would not get fixated on a specific APOC procedure, as it may be too complicated to get its results in the format you want. It seems using raw Cypher should work. But it is still not clear what your use case is. Whenever you make a query, do you expect all the matching paths to have the same pattern (with respect to the sequence of nodes and relationships)?

Comment: @cybersam in this instance I know I want to get to a certain labeled node.  In my example above called it FINAL_NODE.  In the route to FINAL_NODE, traversing from where I am at, I know it will 2 types of relationships and then the final type of relationship (a 3rd type) will be a different direction. in the apoc query it's <TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT|<TO_ATL|TO_FINAL>.  I've gotten it to work where I can get the last one in the line using just regular cypher, but not sure how to do the proper pattern matching.  If that still doesn't make sense, I can try and put up more examples.

Comment: I am asking for a clearer description of your general use case (not the specific one shown in your question, for which I already provided an answer), since is what you seem to you seem to want an answer to.

Comment: @cybersam at the end of the post I added some additional clarification under "additional clarification".  it's really about the variable pattern of the middle section and being able to manipulate the data.  It seems based on your answers and responses it isn't generally straightforward or usual to manipulate the path data when it's a variable pattern.  I appreciate the back and forth and time spent on it.  If nothing jumps out to you, no problem.  I'll just figure out a different way

Comment: So, matching paths could have different lengths, the relationship types can occur in different orders, and the nodes can have different types?

Comment: @cybersam correct, I only know for sure the start node and the final node type I want to get to, but everything else is variable

Comment: It should be possible to come up with Cypher code, but it would take some effort and probably be pretty complex. It would probably be better for you to just take the result of `MATCH p=(f:Red {key:'someid'}<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT|TO_ATL*]-()-[:SOURCE_FOR_INC]->(g:Green)
RETURN p` and generate the data you want in some external programming language. Most of the time, the paths are what people want, so Cypher is geared towards that.

Comment: @cybersam I agree that trying to do a complex cypher query isn't worth it when I can just manipulate once I get it back into C#.  If you make this comment another answer, I'll accept it as I think it's correct.  It seems that with a variable type path like this, it doesn't make sense to try and manipulate the data before returning like you said.

Comment: New answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to come up with Cypher code, but it would take some effort and probably be pretty complex.

It would probably be better for you to just take the result of:

```
MATCH p=(f:Red {key:'someid'}<-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT|TO_ATL*]-()-[:SOURCE_FOR_INC]->(g:Green)
RETURN p
```

and generate the data you want in some external programming language.
Most of the time, paths are what people want, so Cypher is geared towards that.

Answer (score 0):

This query (with some assumed node labels), which does not use the APOC procedure, may work for you:

```
MATCH (f:Node {key:'someid'})
  <-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT]-(t:Teal)
  <-[:ATL_TO_DRAFT]-(r:Red)
  <-[:TO_ACTIVE_DRAFT]-(b:Blue)
  -[:SOURCE_FOR_INC]->(g:Green)
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT f), COLLECT(DISTINCT t), COLLECT(DISTINCT r), COLLECT(DISTINCT b), COLLECT(DISTINCT g)
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't have a guaranteed path, but that is exactly what I'm trying to return.  I updated the question with that clarification and a sample data generation. It seems that in all apoc examples they basically just return the yielded result and don't do anything with it.  I'm looking to be able to create a similar graph to what is generated in the UI of the browser, but with only certain properties.  It means trying to know where the node "fits", but I seem to lose all context when moving it to Nodes and not exactly sure what good the returned "path" is